# "[object Object]" in Event Category of Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

After installing google analytics js on a web page, I get
"[object Object]" in the analytics dashboard, same like this guy: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/object-object-in-event-category-of-google-analytics/

What does it mean, and how do I avoid it? Judging by the number of occurrences per 30 mins, it looks like it's "outta control"

I have a dozen like this:

```
ga('send', 'event', { eventAction: 'clickStartVideoChat', eventCategory: 'VideoChat'} )
```

and

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-YYYY', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to pass all fields in [fieldsObject](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#the_send_method)-parameter:

```js
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'VideoChat',
  eventAction: 'clickStartVideoChat'
});
```

Comment: the issue is still there

Answer (score 0):

Note, changing it now won't change data that's currently in GA. It will only solve the issue for NEW events captured.

You have two options: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

```
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventAction: 'clickStartVideoChat', 
  eventCategory: 'VideoChat'
});
```

**OR**

```
ga('send', 'event', 'VideoChat', 'clickStartVideoChat');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the right post to put this on, but i hope someone finds it useful. This is an implementation of gtag/Google Analytics 4 using Next JS 13.0.0.

```js
      <Script
        strategy="afterInteractive"
        src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js? 
        id=${GA_MEASUREMENT_ID}`}
      />
      <Script
        strategy="afterInteractive"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
            gtag('config', '${GA_MEASUREMENT_ID}' , {
              page_path: window.location.pathname,
            });
          `,
        }}
      />
```

Here is an example implementation of a custom event:

```js
export const product_added_to_cart = (product_code) => {
    if(typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.gtag){
        window.gtag('event' , 'product_added_to_cart',
             {
                'code': product_code,
            })
    }
}
```